# Insert figure in one column?

Tags: floats, captions, multicol

I want to insert a figure into a column, which means a figure uses 0.5*paper width.And the paper are written in two columns.
At the same time, I need to use \bicaption{}{},which is in bicaption package, to create two captions for one figure.

`\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\begin{document}
xxxx......
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figure A}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}`

The problem is,in this case, the figure can not display in a pdf document.

Note, I want to write a paper in one column at the title, and in two column at the text. The text begins at the title page. For example,[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You can't. You can't use a float in a `multicols` environment. See page 5 of the documentation.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates of questions. It makes a mess, makes it more difficult to see which questions don't have answers and is really confusing!